# AWS Organisations list_accounts returns accounts from non-org management account

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-organizations

I am not sure this is by design.

I've found that the below command is fine to get `list_accounts()` from an AWS Organizations Root account or its client account.

```
import boto3
orgClient = boto3.client('organizations')

print(orgClient.list_accounts())
```

My understanding is, that `list_accounts` should be only working on the organization management account.

Why do I still get the same result from the client account as well?

Comment: Is your client account an admin account? “ This operation can be called only from the organization's management account or by a member account that is a delegated administrator for an Amazon Web Services service.”

Comment: you are right. the client account is one of delegate admin account for some AWS Organizations Services. When I run the same python script to a normal account, I did get permisisno deny error.

Comment: Yes :) it is secure by design, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Boto3 docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/organizations.html#Organizations.Client.list_accounts) for `list_accounts`:

> This operation can be called only from the organization's management account or by a member account that is a delegated administrator for an Amazon Web Services service.

Are you calling the operation from a delegated administrator account?

Comment: Thanks, do you know `paginate` . I found even I use `paginate` to list accounts, I still don't get all accounts. any sample for me to get all accounts under the organizations? I can start a new topic about it.

Comment: can you help me for this question as well?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72080723/in-aws-orgazination-use-paginate-to-list-all-accounts