# in aws orgazination, use paginate to list all accounts

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-organizations

This should be a generic question about the usage `paginate` in boto3.

In this case, when I get a lot of accounts (100+) under AWS Orgazinations, use `list_account()` directly without with `NextToken`, you can't list all accounts.

```
response = client.list_accounts()
```

I knew the correct way is adding `NextToken` and `MaxResults`, but that needs more coding.

```
response = client.list_accounts(
    NextToken='string',
    MaxResults=123
)
```

So I switch to use another method, called `paginate`, ref [class Organizations.Paginator.ListAccounts](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/organizations.html#Organizations.Paginator.ListAccounts). It reports more accounts than `list_accounts()`, but still can't list all of them.

the Request Syntax has similar `MaxItems` and `PageSize` as in `list_accounts()`

```
response_iterator = paginator.paginate(
    PaginationConfig={
        'MaxItems': 123,
        'PageSize': 123,
        'StartingToken': 'string'
    }
)
```

So two questions from me:

- if `paginate` can't list all accounts, what's the point to create it.
- How can I list all accounts with `painate` , any sample codes for me?

Will be appreciated.

Comment: Loop the request until NextToken is null, using NextToken as your new StartingToken every time

Comment: I knew how to loop it, and need add more codes to identify when it is end. But if I can loop, why I need paginate. I can write loop codes with `list_accounts()` as well. Seems there is no simple way to do that. The paginate is misleading.

Comment: Paginate allows you to get more than the page limit size currently - that’s why

Comment: but if it can't get all, what's the point to add this feature? I can loop with old way (list_accounts()) as well.

Comment: It’s your choice - they are an abstraction over the process of iterating just to unify a standard across Boto3. Also: you can filter server-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i am wrong, maybe at beginning.

the paginator does handle the loop automatically. I can't run test on Organization `list_accounts()`, because I don't have so many accounts to run the test, but I did a test on s3 bucket objects.

#### aws cli to get s3 objects

```
$ aws s3api list-objects --bucket bucket-demo |jq '.Contents|length'

8696
```

So I can confirm there are 8000+ objects in this bucket.

#### Get s3 object by python sdk with paginator

```
>>> import boto3
>>> client = boto3.client('s3')
>>> paginator = client.get_paginator('list_objects')
>>> response_iterator = paginator.paginate(Bucket="bucket-demo")
>>> for i in response_iterator:
...   print(len(i['Contents']))
...
1000
1000
1000
1000
1000
1000
1000
1000
696
```

it proves the paginator does the loop automatically.

#### show the problem why we need paginator

```
>>> import boto3
>>> client = boto3.client('s3')
>>> response = client.list_objects(Bucket="bucket-demo")
>>> len(response['Contents'])
1000
```

So paginator can similify your codes a lot and avoid to develop own loop with normal way.